# Can we have two different values for each replicas in kubernets statefulset?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, replicaset

I have current implementation like below which takes the same configurations for each replicas.

Is there a possiblity to get the different values for each replica creation ?

statefulset file :

```
{{- $outer := . -}}
{{- range $idx, $app := .Values.appliance_type }}
{{- with $outer -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ $app.name }}
  labels:
    app: "{{ $app.appName }}"
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ $app.replicaCount }}
  serviceName: {{ $app.serviceName }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ $app.appName }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ $app.appName }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selfcheck
        image: {{ .Values.image.registry }}/{{ .Values.da.pod.selfcheck.repository}}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        env:
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: CDNHOSTNAME
            value: '{{ $app.hostname }}'
          - name: CUSER
            value: '{{ .Values.da.conf.consoleUser }}'
          - name: CPASSWORD
            value: '{{ .Values.da.conf.consolePassword }}'

{{ end }}
{{- end -}}


===================

values.yaml

appliance_type:
  - name: sethu
    hostname : s1
    replicaCount: 2
    serviceName: da
    appName: test-ac
  - name: ram
    hostname : r1
    replicaCount: 1
    serviceName: ida
    appName: test-ia
```

===================

**Actual Results :**
it will create 3 PODs

sethu-0 => CDNHOSTNAME (s1)

sethu-1 => CDNHOSTNAME (s1)

ram-0   => CDNHOSTNAME (r1)

**Needed Results :**

sethu-0 => CDNHOSTNAME (s1)

sethu-1 => CDNHOSTNAME (s2)

ram-0   => CDNHOSTNAME (r1)

hostname of sethu-0 and sethu-1 need to be taken different values from values.yaml

kind of below configuration - but not working

```
appliance_type:
  - name: sethu
    hostname : 
      - s1
      - s2
    replicaCount: 2
    serviceName: da
    appName: test-ac
  - name: ram
    replicaCount: 1
    serviceName: ida
    appName: test-ia
```

Comment: Kubernetes already gives each StatefulSet a unique hostname with a known, sequential format; can you just use that hostname as is?  Aside from a couple of details like that hostname and the specific PVC that gets mounted, the pods will otherwise be identical.

Comment: @DavidMaze I need hostname to be configured with values input. not the unique one which gives by default. ehh ok may be i wanted to append different prefix for each hostname.